# javascript for loop only return the last element

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, for-loop, foreach

**Why the loop only return the last value?**

Can someone help me to get all the values return in the `SQL insert`

```
tableau.forEach(function(obj) {

    for(let i = 0; i < obj.produits.length; i++) {
        let bd_nom = obj.produits[ii].nom
        let bd_description = obj.produits[ii].description
        let bd_titre = obj.titre

        records = [[bd_nom, bd_description, bd_titre]]

        con.connect(function(err) {
            let sql = "INSERT INTO scrapeded (nom, text, titre) VALUES ?";
            con.query(sql, [records], function (err, result) {
                console.log(result)
                console.log("Nombre de rangée affectée : " + result.affectedRows)
                console.log("Nombre d'enregistrement affectée avec avertissement : " + result.warningCount)
                console.log("Message du serveur mySQL : " + result.message)
            })
         })
      }
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

You're implicitly assigning and reassigning to the global variable `records` on each iteration. So, by the time the asynchronous query starts, the main thread has ended and `records` remains as the last value it was assigned.

Declare it with `const` instead to ensure that there's a new binding for each iteration.

Also, there's no need to declare an array and then immediately destructure it to select the first element - instead, simply declare `records` as a single-dimensional array with two items:

```
tableau.forEach(function(obj) {
  for(let i = 0; i < obj.produits.length; i++) {
    let bd_nom = obj.produits[ii].nom
    let bd_description = obj.produits[ii].description
    let bd_titre = obj.titre

    const records = [bd_nom, bd_description, bd_titre]

    con.connect(function(err) {
      let sql = "INSERT INTO scrapeded (nom, text, titre) VALUES ?";
      con.query(sql, records, function (err, result) {
        console.log(result)
        console.log("Nombre de rangée affectée : " + result.affectedRows)
        console.log("Nombre d'enregistrement affectée avec avertissement : " + result.warningCount)
        console.log("Message du serveur mySQL : " + result.message)
      })
    })
  }
})
```